# Proof that an affine scheme is quasi compact

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that any affine scheme $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ is compact.

$\bigcup D(f_i)$ is an open cover of $X$ if and only if the sum ideal $\sum (f_i)$ contains $1$. That is, $ D(\sum f_i)=\bigcup D(f_i)$.

Why does a possible infinite sum of ideals which includes $1$ mean that there exists a finite subset of such ideal whose ideal sum will include $1$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{a}_i \subseteq A$ is an ideal for each $i \in Y$, $Y$ a set of any size, then $\sum_i \mathfrak{a}_i$ is (by definition) the set of all finite sums of elements of the $\mathfrak{a}_i$. So if $1 \in \sum_i \mathfrak{a}_i$, then there exist $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ and elements $f_{i_k} \in \mathfrak{a}_{i_k}$ such that $$f_{i_1}+\cdots+f_{i_n}=1.$$

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that was the definition. Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, the reason why that's the definition is because $\sum_i \mathfrak{a}_i$ is precisely the ideal generated by $\bigcup_i \mathfrak{a}_i$.

Answer (score 4):

$1\in\sum(f_i)$ implies that $1=\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}a_{i_j}f_{i_j}$, thus $\bigcup_{j=1}^{j=n}D(f_{i_j})=Spec(A)$.

Comment: I think your first implication is what I am asking about. Why is there necessarily such a finite sum?

Comment: By definition, an element of $\sum(f_i)$ is a finite sum $\sum a_{i_j}f_{i_j}$ or a sum $\sum a_if_i$ such that only finitely many $a_i$ are not zero and the two assertions are equivalent. Thus $1\in \sum (f_i)$ implies that $1=\sum a_{i_j}f_{i_j}$