# existence of infinitely many connected components implies that a space is not connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let a topological space $X$ have infinitely many connected components.  Then why is it true that $X=X_1 \cup X_2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are closed, disjoint nonempty?

For example $X=\mathbb{Q}$ has as its components each point, and $X=(-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cup (\sqrt{2}, \infty)$.

Motivation:

I am trying to prove that in $\operatorname{Spec}A$, the connected components are clopen sets when $A$ is a noetherian ring. It suffices to show that there are finitely many connected components. A positive answer to this question would let me prove that there are finitely many connected components by contradiction  - I would separate $\operatorname{Spec}A$ by two closed subsets and separate the one that is not connected(again by the positive answer to my question), and use that $A$ is noetherian to get a contradiction.

Comment: Is $X$ a Hausdorff ($T_2$) space? Are the connected components of $X$ countable?

Comment: In the application that I am interested in, $X$ will be $T_0$.  It won't be $T_2$. I am willing to work with countable components first if that is easier

Comment: An affine scheme is quasi compact (no noetherianness needed) and therefore can only have finitely many connected component. This is just a comment to your motivation part. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872170/proof-that-an-affine-scheme-is-quasi-compact

Comment: In addition to closed and disjoint, you want $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be non-empty

Comment: @MaikPickl  But that won't help me prove what I want.  First it is not true for arbitrary rings that the connected components of $Spec A$ are open.   Second, I would have the show that the connected components are open first, (after which it would follow that the connected components form an open cover of $Spec A$).  This defeats the purpose because I am trying to show that the connected components are open.

Comment: Regarding your motivation, and just as an aside: the "standard" way to deduce this (I think) is to use the fact that even the number of *irreducible* comps. of Spec $A$ is finite.  (This corresponds to a familiar ideal-theoretic statement about Noetherian rings, and can also be proved by Noetherian induction, similarly to your argument about connected comps.)  But your direct argument looks like it works too.

Answer (score 3):

Connected component is defined as a inclusion-maximal connected subset. As soon as you have a component $X_1\subsetneq X$, it follows that $X$ is not connected (as otherwise $X_1$ would not be maximal).

Comment: thanks!  guess I will think about my question more before asking next time.